# Step 2 of Windows liveUSB instructions are not clear to me

Tags: usb

I want to make a bootable USB stick.

I run the UUI.

I see the instructions on [Official Ubuntu](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/create-a-usb-stick-on-windows) site

Step 1 says:
Select "Ubuntu Desktop Edition" from the dropdown list

Okay, so the actual title of the drop down box is:
Select a "Linux Distribution" from the dropdown to put on your USB

I am pretty new to computers. 67 years old. Live alone. Bought my first computer 3 months ago. So I will have to assume that when the instructions say "Ubuntu Desktop Edition", that means the same thing as "Linux Distribution".  Okay, No big leap there.  So far, so good.

So I pick the very first selection:
Ubuntu 13.10 Desktop i386

I'm not sure why there are so many choices, but I'm guessing I'm pretty safe with the first one. It's for a Toshiba Satellite laptop 64 bit Windows 7.

Okay, now for step 2:

The instructions say:
Click 'Browse' and open the downloaded ISO file.

The message in the window just before the "Browse" button says:
Browse to your ubuntu-13.10*desktop*i386.iso  -->

Okay, so where's that file?
So I click "Browse" and start looking for that file.
It is nowhere to be found.

So where the is it?

Comment: You will have to download the ISO file. Please go through the instructions in this site http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/install-desktop-latest . You can also google for a step by step tutorial on how to install.

Answer (score 0):

As far as step 1, you guessed correctly. (To be more exact, "Linux Distribution" is a category, and "Ubuntu Desktop Edition" falls into that category.)

"Ubuntu 13.10 Desktop i386" should work fine with your computer, but you might consider picking "Ubuntu 13.10 Desktop amd64" if you gives the option. The browse button is for if you already had a copy of Ubuntu. In your case, you want to instead check the box that says "Download the ISO (optional)". This should automatically retrieve Ubuntu from the internet for you.

Comment: @AlbertFrye You're welcome. If my answer did solve your question, could please check the green checkmark next to my answer to mark your question as solved?